# How detect a click on a given period of time and made manipulation with element in this period

Tags: javascript

may be some one can help me. I try to write some "Dote game":  1. at a specified time interval a random square on the field is highlighted in blue. 2. If the user managed to click on the square during this time - it turns green if not it turns red.  I am stuck with the second part. Here is my code:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let lower = 1,
    upper = 10,
    uniqueN = [];

while (uniqueN.length < upper) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * upper + lower);
    if (uniqueN.indexOf(random) == -1) {
        uniqueN.push(random);
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function loop() {
        let square = document.getElementById(uniqueN.shift());
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        if (uniqueN.length) {
            setTimeout(loop, 3000);
        }
        square.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // pseudo code:
            // if I click this square in the next 2 seconds
            // background color change to the green,
            // if I don't click,
            // or click after 2 seconds color change to red
            //
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: can you upload your code in a fiddle.js

Comment: it would help to have the html code as well, ideally in a jsfiddle

Comment: A question. Does the time has to be accurate, so does it have to be exact 2 seconds for example? Otherwise you could use a nested timeout and simply set a flag.

Comment: @DustinGogoll time can be different(3s, 1s, 0.5s...), but const. I mean if you start to play with 2s so the whole game must go with this interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a couple bits of state with the items. In this case, you can use `ready` for when the button is ready to be clicked on and `clicked` when the button has been clicked.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let lower = 1,
    upper = 10,
    items = [];

while (items.length < upper) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * upper + lower);
    
    if (!items.find(u => u.id === random)) {
        items.push({
          id: random,
          ready: false,
          clicked: false,
        });
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function loop() {
        let item = items.shift();
        let square = document.getElementById(item.id);
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        
        // mark the item ready
        item.ready = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            // hasn't been clicked within 2 seconds
            if (!item.clicked) {
                square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
            // mark it not ready after 2 seconds
            item.ready = false;
        }, 2000);
        
        if (items.length) {
            setTimeout(loop, 3000);
        }
        square.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // pseudo code:
            // if I click this square in the next 2 seconds
            // background color change to the green,
            // if I don't click,
            // or click after 2 seconds color change to red
            
            // if clicked on when ready, store the state
            if (item.ready) {
                item.clicked = true;
                square.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">button</button>

<div>
  <button id="1">1</button>
  <button id="2">2</button>
  <button id="3">3</button>
  <button id="4">4</button>
  <button id="5">5</button>
  <button id="6">6</button>
  <button id="7">7</button>
  <button id="8">8</button>
  <button id="9">9</button>
  <button id="10">10</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If this works for you and are using it, please accept the answer

Comment: yes, it works very well, thank you! I accepted the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not easy (if not impossible) getting this value inside the `setTumeout` function. The best approach would be to use javascript `Date` object with the `.now()` method. Here's how your code might look like

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let lower = 1,
    upper = 10,
    uniqueN = [];

while (uniqueN.length < upper) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * upper + lower);
    if (uniqueN.indexOf(random) == -1) {
        uniqueN.push(random);
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // -------------time at the begining of the timeout----------
    const start = Date.now();

    setTimeout(function loop() {
        let square = document.getElementById(uniqueN.shift());
        square.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        if (uniqueN.length) {
            setTimeout(loop, 3000);
        }
        square.addEventListener('click', function() {

            //------------time elasped since the begining of timeout---------
            const elapsed = Date.now() - start;
            if (elapsed <= 2000) {
                // background color change to the green,
            } else {
                // or click after 2 seconds color change to red
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes your right it is not easy (at least for me:))! It starts to work on click correctly if we put "const start = Date.now();" inside of the "setTimeout". I'll try just to fix 'change color to red' if don't click

Comment: @VovkaYemelyanov Cool. Please upvote the answer if it did help